# The physical meaning of the action of the following operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics, lie-algebra

I've been thinking about different realisations of the two-mode bosonic Lie algebras and faced the following misunderstanding.

It is possible to consider different unitary operators, such as the squeeze operator
$$
S(z) = \exp(z^* ab - z a^\dagger b^\dagger),
$$
which action on the Fock or on the coherent state is clear to me.

I'm interested in the result of the action of the following operator
$$
?(z) = \exp(z^* ab^\dagger \pm z a^\dagger b ),
$$

on the Fock state $|n,k\rangle$ or on the coherent state $|\alpha, \beta\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2 - |\beta|^2/2}\sum_{n,k} \frac{\alpha^n \beta^k}{\sqrt{n! k!}} | n,k\rangle$?

P.S. I'm looking for something like this (journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.49.4957) or (journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.3854), but for the mentioned operator $?()$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137522/discussion-on-question-by-mightypower-the-physical-meaning-of-the-action-of-the).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that one's easy.
Using
\begin{align}
L_+=\hat a^\dagger \hat b\, \quad 
L_-=\hat a \hat b^\dagger\, ,\quad 
L_z=\frac{1}{2}[L_+,L_-]
\end{align}
you operator $S(z)$ can in fact be written as
$$
\exp(i \alpha L_z)\exp(-i\beta L_y)\exp(-i \alpha L_z) \tag{1}
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are related to $z$ and $z^*$.

First use
$z=\vert z\vert (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ and then rewrite $z^*L_-+zL_+$ as a combination of $L_x$ and $L_y$, then use
$$
\exp(i \alpha L_z) L_y \exp(-i \alpha L_z)=
L_y\cos\alpha + L_x\sin\alpha
$$
to reach (1).

Next, using the Schwinger realization, the 2-mode state $\vert n_1,n_1\rangle$ maps to the angular momentum state $\vert j m\rangle$ where $j=\frac{1}{2}(n_1+n_2), m=\frac{1}{2}(n_1-n_2)$.
so it's then a simple matter to go from
\begin{align}
\exp(z^* ab^\dagger + z a^\dagger b)\vert n_1,n_2\rangle&\to 
R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\alpha)\vert j m\rangle_{a,b}\, ,\\
&=\sum_{m'}\vert jm'\rangle D^{j}_{m'm}(\alpha,\beta,-\alpha)\\
&\to \sum_{a'b'}\vert a'b'\rangle D^{j}_{m'm}(\alpha,\beta,-\alpha)\, .
\end{align}

Thus, your operator unitarily scatters a state with a fixed number of excitations to other states with the same total number of excitations.  For applications see for instance the seminal work of

> Yurke B, McCall SL, Klauder JR. SU (2) and SU (1, 1) interferometers. Physical Review A. 1986 Jun 1;33(6):4033.

Comment: Oh, I finally figured out how to deal with another basis regarding my initial problem. Thank you a lot!